# Why doesn't my component callback work as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, components

I'm trying to follow http://www.codelord.net/2016/05/13/understanding-angulars-and-binding/ to implement a callback on an AngularJS component.  At https://plnkr.co/edit/dxyI0p0pZFZdMalLfvXO?p=preview I've tried to illustrate the problem I'm having.  I instantiate the component in three different ways:

```
<section id="main-content" ng-controller="myPageController as ctrl">
<my-component label="Scope" myChange="cb()"></my-component>
<my-component label="Ctrl" myChange="ctrl.cb()"></my-component>
<my-component label="Page" myChange="page.cb()"></my-component>
</section>
```

But none of them work.  I see the message logged by the function tied to the checkbox in the component but I don't see the message from the callback nor do I see any error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Code elves set their hand to my Plunker yesterday and it seems to work today.  Why is a mystery to me.

Comment: I'm back to reviewing this again and I notice one major discrepancy between the working Plunker and my code was that I was neglecting the change from `the-identifier` as used to `theIdentifier` as implemented in the component.

Answer (score 0):

"onchange" is a reserved attribute of HTML elements.
use a different name, like myChange.
see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onchange.asp

Comment: Thanks for that advice -- I will change the name -- but when I change "onChange" to "onChanageCb" I don't get errors from any of the instantiations but the callback doesn't get called, either.

Comment: I'm guessing that with `onChange` it's not the component calling the function as a callback but another event handler tied to the element.  This is actually closer to my original failure in my application where the callback doesn't get invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/OYpLu8/

If you change you file `myPage.inc` to this:

```
<section id="main-content" ng-controller="myPageController as ctrl">

    <h2>This is the page.</h2>
    <my-component label="Scope"  ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="cb()"></my-component>
    <my-component label="Ctrl"  ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="ctrl.cb()"></my-component>
    <my-component label="Page"  ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="page.cb()"></my-component>

</section>
```

But it only resolves the `ng-change` problem.

These `ng-model` don't do anything, this model `confirmed` even doesn't exist in any controller, it's here just to `ng-change` works.

---

**Edit: You need pass the function into the directive to this function get called. The way you do that is creating a `scope` inside your directive.**

```
'scope': {
  'yourFunction': '&'
}
```

And call it inside your `component`.

```
<label>{{vm.label}}</label>

<input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.handleCheckboxClick()" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="yourFunction()"/><br>
```

And now, everytime that you want to call a outsider function, you need to pass this function to your `component`.

```
<my-component label="Scope" your-function="cb()"></my-component>
<my-component label="Ctrl"  your-function="ctrl.cb()"></my-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I see the same behavior in your Plunker that I saw in mine.  Even if your technique worked, it would solve the specific problem of change tracking, not the general problem of component callbacks.

Comment: I edited to properly answer you. I hope that I solved your problem.

Comment: I got code like yours to call the function I pass to the component when the checkbox is changed.  But I find it odd that I have to assign it as an `ng-change` handler on every checkbox.  I really wanted a more general solution which the component controller could call when appropriate.  Like, maybe I have multiple check boxes in the component and I want to invoke the callback when they are all in the same state.